# Which EventBus is preferable for new Desktop Applications?

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, event-bus

For several years we use `org.bushe.swing.event.EventBus` for mainly swing desktop applications. The API is really consistent, and easy to use. But now new requirements have arrised and its desired, that some EventSubscribers should get prefered over others, since they are informed synchronisly. So some kind of priority factor is needed for those subscribers.

Extending EventBus to priorize EventSubscribers shouldnt be that much of a problem, but since `org.bushe.swing.event.EventBus` has gone stale, I am not sure, if it might be preferable to change the EventBus Implementation.

[org.bushe.swing.event.EventBus](http://eventbus.org/) itself recommends projects like [GWT Eventbus](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html) for GWT. I'm not sure, if that is also a good approach for swing applications. Which EventBus Implementations do you usually use? Do you may even know a simple Implementations which supports Priorities for Subscribers?

Comment: Maybe this comparison will be useful to you http://codeblock.engio.net/?p=37.

Comment: Thats a perfect start for getting an overview over Eventbus Implementations. The document even states, that bushe.EventBus has already the possiblity of priorize handlers, which I didn't know yet. I'll have a closer look. thanks!